# Where to put modules for different configurations of same kernel version?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, modprobe

To what I see the modules for different kernel versions are stored below 
`/lib/modules`, i.e as `/lib/modules/{version}/...../...ko`

Now, while this makes it evident where to store the modules for each different *kernel version*, I have currently changed the `.config` (i.e. what I think is the configuration) of a kernel I have already have.

My question is where would the modules for this new *kernel configuration* of the now two times existing *kernel version* go?
Would `/lib/modules/{version}_{configsuffix}/...../...ko` be the way?

How would a tool like `modprobe` know where to find those modules?

Additionally I also want to state my suspicion that for a fair share of the modules, even different values in the kernel's configuration `.config` would lead to the same identical kernel module. Yet even in this case there might be some settings in the `.config` to make adjust the modules and hence create different modules even for the same *kernel version*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you change the configuration, add a suffix that succintly describes the configuration to the `EXTRAVERSION` field of the Makefile.

```
EXTRAVERSION=-lpae
```

and another time

```
EXTRAVERSION=-486
```

That way different configurations are different versions as far as all the tooling is involved: different output from `uname -r`, different subdirectories in `/lib/modules`, etc.

That's what most distributions do.